# Missing FBSessionStateOpen from facebook SDK [Firebase Ref.,Swift]

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, firebase

I'm trying to connect firebase and facebook as referencing here
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/facebook.html#section-authenticating

Version of FacebookSDK 3.21.1

This is the line I have problem with

```
state.value == FBSessionStateOpen.value
```

FBSessionStateOpen are unresolved identifier
[image]

I have already create Bridge-Header which contain

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

I have seen that in FacebookSDK.framework already contain FBSessionStateOpen in FBSession.h

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FBSessionState) {
    ...
    /*! Open session state indicating user has logged in or a cached token is available */
    FBSessionStateOpen                      = 1 | FB_SESSIONSTATEOPENBIT,
    ...
};
```

**Full Code** from firebase

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com")
FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], allowLoginUI: true,
     completionHandler: { session, state, error in

    if error != nil {
        println("Facebook login failed. Error \(error)")
    } else if state.value == FBSessionStateOpen.value {
        let accessToken = session.accessTokenData.accessToken
        ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken,
            withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in

            if error != nil {
                println("Login failed. \(error)")
            } else {
                println("Logged in! \(authData)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this beautiful question down rated? I had the similar problem too.

Answer (score 2):

I have try to change the statement to and it works!

from

```
state.value == FBSessionStateOpen.value
```

to

```
state.hashValue == FBSessionState.Open.hashValue
```

Although I'm not sure if its how it should be or not.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
func login(callback: () -> Void){

        let permission = ["email","user_location","user_birthday","user_hometown","user_photos","user_about_me"];

        let activeSession = FBSession.activeSession();
        let fbsessionState = activeSession.state;
        var showLoginUI = true;

        if(fbsessionState == FBSessionState.CreatedTokenLoaded){
            showLoginUI = false;
        }

        if(fbsessionState != FBSessionState.Open
            && fbsessionState != FBSessionState.OpenTokenExtended){
                FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(
                    permission,
                    allowLoginUI: showLoginUI,
                    completionHandler: { (session:FBSession!, state:FBSessionState, error:NSError!) in

                        if(error != nil){
                            println("Session Error: \(error)");
                        }

                        self.fbSession = session;

                        callback();

                    }
                );
                return;
        }

        callback();

    }
```